# RxJs one request

Tags: c#, rxjs

Html two times invoke `Test()` how to make only one request? Is it possible to do without subscribe function?

**Html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of Items$ | async">
    {{item}}
</div>
<h1>{{randomItem | async}}</h1>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("test")]
public IEnumerable<string> Test()
{
    return new List<string>() { "First", "Second", "Third" };
}
```

**Component:**

```
export class KindsComponent {

  constructor(private kindsService: KindsService) { }

  public kindViewModel$: Observable<KindViewModel> = this.kindsService.kindViewModel$;

  public Items$: Observable<string[]> = this.kindsService.Items$;
  
  public randomItem = this.Items$.pipe(map(projects => projects.filter(proj => proj === 'First')));
}
```

**Update.**

**Service:**

```
public Items$ = this.http.get<string[]>('https://localhost:44338/api/kind/test')
.pipe(
  tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)),
    catchError(this.handleError))
);
```

Comment: How does Items$ in the service look like? Did you add .pipe(shareReplay()) to the http request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have two `async` pipes in the template, you will end up with two subscriptions to the observable.

As @MatterOfFact mentioned, you could add [`shareReplay()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) to your source so that a single subscription is shared:

> You generally want to use shareReplay when you have side-effects or taxing computations that you do not wish to be executed amongst multiple subscribers

```
public Items$ = this.http.get<string[]>('https://localhost:44338/api/kind/test')
   .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)),
      catchError(this.handleError)),
      shareReplay()
);
```

---

You could also change your `randomItem` observable property to be a method that pulls a random item out of the array, then you wouldn't need two different observables.

Controller:

```
public getRandomItem(projects: string[]) {
   return projects.filter(proj => proj === 'First')
}
```

Template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="Items$ | async as items">
   <div *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{item}}
   </div>
   <h1>{{ getRandomItem(items) }}</h1>
</ng-container>
```